# How to reload udev rules without reboot?

Tags: kernel, udev

How should one reload udev rules, so that newly created one can function?

I'm running Arch Linux, and I don't have a `udevstart` command here.

Also checked `/etc/rc.d`, no udev service there.

Comment: Please note that more recent versions of udev have dropped the inotify support so the reloading of the rules on change is needed more often these days.

Comment: What is `udev`? Is it the manager of `/dev` ?

Comment: @Sandburg yes it handles plug-n-play on Linux systems.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

Comment: Do you need `udevtrigger` afterwards?

Comment: @Nils Actually, you may need `udevtrigger` (or rather `udevadm trigger` on most distributions) instead (that, or plug the device out and back it). `--reload-rules` is almost always useless as it happens automatically.

Comment: `udevadm trigger` did the trick on CentOS 6 for me.

Comment: `udevtrigger` or `udevadm trigger` did not work for me. I found some devices will work after unloading and loading the module for the same (assuming it is loadable module). What I found out is one does not necessarily have to reboot the system. Example for a network device, I do `rmmod ixgbe`, `rmmod tg3`,`rmmod e1000` then `modprobe ixgbe`, `modprobe tg3`,`modprobe e1000` depending on type of network driver.

Comment: Neither of things mentioned among the answers worked for me on Debian Jessie (8.0). The thing which worked is `ip link set $oldname name $newname` mentioned [here](http://kernelpanik.net/rename-a-linux-network-interface-without-udev/). In my case, I needed to replace an iface named `lan` with a bridged iface (for KVM), and hence the original--now underlying--iface had to get its old name, `eth1`, back. So the trick was: 1) bring iface down; 2) fix network config up; 3) update udev naming rules file; 4) rename the iface using `ip link...`; 5) bring the bridge up.

Comment: Don't forget, you may need to unplug and plug the device back in to load the new rules for it.

Comment: for remote pcs and usb disks: `modprobe -r usb_storage ; modprobe usb_storage`

Comment: I did have to `sudo udevadm trigger` after this, though removing the sudo didn't show any error, I didn't actually see any change until I ran it w/ sudo

Comment: On Debian testing 'udevadm trigger' does not work. I had to unplug and plug usb ethernet card only then udev triggered new rule.

Comment: I required `sudo udevadm trigger` instead of `udevadm trigger` as well. See my comments under this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048870/permission-denied-to-non-root-user-for-usb-device/1187646#1187646. Doing it *with* sudo took ~2 sec, but doing it withOUT sudo took only ~0.2 sec. So clearly they are not doing the same thing for me.

Comment: @JacobMinshall, if you or anyone else confirms `sudo` is in fact required, as I think it is, here's an answer for that to be upvoted to indicate that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot/567996#567996.

Comment: For some reason, `sudo udevadm test /sys/bus/net/can0` (change for your device), triggered device renaming for me.

Comment: `$ sudo udevadm control --reload` is all that is needed.

Comment: Note that `udevadm trigger` performs a udev "change". If you want to trigger an "add", or if you want to be more specific, check out @mbadmin 's answer.

Answer (score 90):

Udev uses the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) mechanism to watch for changes in the rules directory, in both the library and in the local configuration trees (typically located at `/lib/udev/rules.d` and `/etc/udev/rules.d`). So most of the time you don't need to do anything when you change a rules file.

You only need to notify the udev daemon explicitly if you're doing something unusual, for example if you have a rule that includes files in another directory. Then you can use the usual convention for asking daemons to reload their configuration: send a [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (`pkill -HUP udevd`). Or you can use the [`udevadm`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm) command: `udevadm control --reload-rules`.

However, beware that different versions of udev have historically had different triggers for reloading the rules automatically. So if in doubt, call `udevadm control --reload-rules`: it won't do any harm anyway.

The udev rules are only applied when a device is added. If you want to reapply the rules to a device that is already connected, you need to do this explicitly, by calling `udevadm trigger` with the right options to match the device(s) whose configuration has changed, e.g. `udevadm trigger --attr-match=vendor='Yoyodyne' --attr-match=model='Frobnicator 300'`.

Comment: Does systemd udev use inotify to watch for rule changes?

Comment: The `inotify` mechanism does not always catch a change of a udev rule file. For example when I use `cat > 10-name.rules` to change the rule file by pasting the contents, I have to reload rules manually using `udevadm`. Tested on Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: @DanielK. Has this changed recently? IIRC I checked both a systemd udev and a non-systemd udev when I posted this answer, and both did use inotify, so `--reload-rules` was only needed in uncommon cases.

Comment: @Gilles: maybe my example above (overwriting an existing rule file using shell redirection) can be considered being an "uncommon case". When I modified this file by way of an editor, e.g., vi, the `inotify` mechanism worked.

Comment: @DanielK. Ah, that's good to know. It isn't an uncommon case: some editors would save the file by rewriting (with Vim and Emacs, it depends how they're configured). Weird that udev only handles one of the cases — it looks like a bug to me, because I can't think of a reason to treat them differently.

Answer (score 26):

I'm adding this because some day I will need it... again.

Sometimes you get an incorrect matching of ethernet device numbers and MAC addresses. Sometimes this is really important, like when running in a VM and each device is assigned to a different VLAN.

1. Bring the network interfaces down, then
2. modify `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` (or its equivalent)
3. re-load with `udevadm control --reload-rules`
4. re-trigger with `udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=net`
5. bring the network interfaces up.

I was surprised how well this worked.

Comment: on Red Hat: `service network stop && udevadm control --reload-rules; udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=net; service network start`

Comment: On Debian testing 'udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=net' does not work. I had to unplug and plug usb ethernet card only then udev triggered new rule.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet, Trismegistos, that the unplug/plug is akin to removing and reloading the network driver, as per Clayton Dukes' answer.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure if this applies, and this is definitely an older post but it came up pretty high my web search for udev info so I thought I might share some knowledge.

You can trigger udev rules manually for specific devices. This applies only to redhat-related distros (centos fedora etc etc etc)

Once you make the relevant changes in your rules file (`/etc/udev/rules.d/whateveryoucalledyourrules`), you can echo `change` in to the device's uevent.

```
echo change > /sys/block/devname/partname1/uevent
```

This will force a udev rule reading for ONLY this device. Much better, and more targeted in my opinion.

Comment: This is great. I did a `echo add > /sys/devices/pci0000\:d7/0000\:d7\:00.0/0000\:d8\:00.0/uevent` so I can tell you that it works for non-block devices, as well, and it works to trigger "add" events.

Answer (score 4):

For me, below command sequence has worked as it is desired.

I have done modifications in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to change the `eth` number and to reload them without rebooting.

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
/etc/init.d/udev stop
udevadm control --reload-rules
/etc/init.d/udev start
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

By following this, It was successfully loaded in run time without rebooting the machine.

Any suggestion or recommendations on this are welcome, as I have discovered this on my own by reading the man pages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding the *correct* answer here because it took me a while to notice it in the comment from @enthusiasticgeek.
All you need to do (assuming you are on the console of the server - clearly this is bad to do if you are ssh'd in!):

1. Get a list of the interface module(s) being used:

`cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules | grep "PCI device" | perl -pe 's/.*\((\w+)\).*/$1/g'| uniq`

In my case, it's `igb`, so it prints just that.

2. type `sudo rmmod igb` (replace `igb` with your card driver obtained from step 1.

next, edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` as needed, then load the module again using `modprobe igb`, again replacing `igb` with yours.

Comment: This, combined with Otheus' answer, was the secret sauce that enabled me to fix my Mellanox network card config without a machine reboot. I believe the loading of the driver and the udevadm read of the persistent-net.rules file is roughly akin to what the system does when it's booting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight change from [the main answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39371/114401): `sudo` seemed to be required for me on both commands.

Anecdotal evidence: doing `sudo udevadm trigger` took ~2 sec, but doing it withOUT sudo took only ~0.2 sec. So clearly they are not doing the same thing for me. Do this instead:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```

And then lastly (per the 2nd link below), **unplug your device and plug it back in**.

### References:

1. [How to reload udev rules without reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot/39371#39371)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048870/permission-denied-to-non-root-user-for-usb-device/1187646#1187646

See comments under both of the answers above as well.

Comment: The commands in Igancio's answer have `#` as prompt which implies that they need to be executed as root. Depending on your preference you then may use `sudo` or just execute them in a root shell (which you may enter by e.g. `su -` or `sudo -s` or just log into another console as root).

Comment: Ahhh. That's subtle. I had no idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in case of multiple networks

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules | grep "PCI device" | awk '{print $NF}'|sed -e 's/(//g' -e 's/)//g'| uniq > /tmp/listnet
rm -rf /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
for i in $(cat /tmp/listnet); do rmmod $i; modprobe $i;done
service network restart
rm -rf /tmp/listnet
```