# Map IDE drive to /dev/hda

Tags: linux, debian

I run a small home server with one IDE drive (for the system) and a few SATA drives (for a software RAID).

The IDE drive used to be at `/dev/hda` and the SATA drives at `/dev/sd*`. After a power outage the IDE drive claims to be `/dev/sde` and wreaks havoc with my RAID.

How do I get my IDE drive to behave well again?

Comment: It's in general a bad idea to rely on the order of the drives. udev assigns them dynamically and the order might change. To address a file sytem use the label or the UUID.

Comment: +1 @Marco, [there's some useful information on UUIDs here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID).  (Still the issue itself is weird.  Everything else, besides the name, is behaving fine?  No errors in `dmesg` etc.  The home server being a long-running machine that due to the outage was rebooted for the first time with an updated kernel would be an explanation, I suppose...)

Comment: I suspect the reason things have changed is a while back the ATA subsystem in the linux kernel was changed so that PATA and SATA drives were handled the same, so all ?ATA drives have the device nodes /dev/sd??.  At some point I'm guessing a kernel update has been performed but has not taken effect until this power outage caused you to reboot the system.

Comment: @JRT I agree 100%, actually have had that happen. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in general a bad idea to rely on the order of the drives. udev assigns them dynamically and the order might change.

File systems are better addressed by label or UUID:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/
/dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Use the command `blkid` to find out information about your file systems.

Disks are addresses by id

```
/dev/disk/by-id/
```

If the disk ids are too ugly to work with you can symlink them to e.g. `/dev/mainhdd`, `/dev/backupdrive`, etc. via udev rules. Manual symlinks would not be persistent, since  `/dev` is a kind of ram disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an udev rule to impose a particular device path for a particular device. For example:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{DRIVER}=="ide*", NAME="hda%n"
```

This line goes into a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/59-wukerplank-storage.rules`. It takes effect when the device is added; [you can tell udev to reapply rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot/39485#39485) but this is not a good idea if the device is in use.

Note that you should not rely on names like `hda` or `sda`, they are not expected to be constant. If you need a persistent name for a device, it is best to use udev to create an alias for it:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{model}=="ZXQ-500", ATTRS{serial}=="123456", SYMLINK+="disks/by-alias/zxq"
```

The command `udevadm info -a -n sda` shows what properties you can use to match `/dev/sda`.

RAID configurations normally use a unique identifier (UUID) to tell which disk is which. This is necessary, for example, if you plug the disks in a different machine or in a different order. So it is strange that your RAID would have trouble with device names. If you have custom scripts that depend on device names, make them call `mdadm` to query the components of the array instead.

Comment: Yes, but frankly, I'd rather strangle myself than getting convinced to work with UUIDs in `/etc/fstab`, to begin with. It just messes up the listing with its insanely long hex values (and my eyes, too). They're no less annoying to work with than Class IDs on Windoze.