# How to create a permanent symlink to a device?

Tags: linux

I want to create a symlink to a device.When i tried the command

```
ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/scd0
```

it looked everything well.But when i restarted the server,i found /dev/scd0 is disappered.
How can i create a permanent link?

Comment: Kinda duplicate, kinda not, but your answer can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44627/4358

Comment: IIRC, `/dev`, like `/proc` and `/run` gets populated on boot and disappears into the aether on shutdown, so any symlinks made there will never stick. I worked around a similar issue (USB automount) by symlinking the automountpoint in `/run/media/user/` to `/home/user/usbstick`.

Answer (score 12):

Modern linux distros use udev device manager, so you need to create a udev rule to achieve this.

As a `root` user create a new file named `99_sr0.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with the following contents

```
KERNEL=="sr0", SYMLINK+="scd0"
```

Reboot your PC or run

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules; sudo udevadm trigger
```

to re-run your udev rules and you will see your symlink

```
> ls -l /dev/sr0 /dev/scd0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 May 22 18:54 /dev/scd0 -> sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 May 22 18:54 /dev/sr0
>
```

Comment: … although the question did not actually specify that the symbolic link has to be in `/dev`.  (-:

Comment: I believe it does. Just read the question again :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I wanted a symlink to /dev/ttyS2 as /dev/ttyS0, so created using this line in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-tty.rules:  KERNEL=="ttyS2", SYMLINK+="ttyS0"
Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a solution described in [proxmox wiki](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/ZFS:_Tips_and_Tricks#Example_configurations_for_running_Proxmox_VE_with_ZFS)

> If you have a good number of disks keep organized by using aliases. Edit /etc/zfs/vdev_id.conf to prepare aliases for disk devices found in /dev/disk/by-id/ :
> run 'udevadm trigger' after updating this file

```
alias a0        scsi-36848f690e856b10018cdf39854055206
alias b0        scsi-36848f690e856b10018cdf3ce573fdeb6
alias a1        scsi-36848f690e856b10018cdf40f5b277cbc
alias b1        scsi-36848f690e856b10018cdf43a5db1b99b
alias a2        scsi-36848f690e856b10018cdf4575f652ad0
alias b2        scsi-36848f690e856b10018cdf47761587cec
```

Seems it can solve OP's problem quite elegantly, I also think using /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-xxx is more appropriate, since is guaranteed not to changed even if the disk is moved to another system.

Comment: `/dev/disk/by-id/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` avoids any user created aliases.