# Restarting udev on CentOS 6 (tethering a mobile phone using proxoid)

Tags: centos, udev, services

I am trying to use proxoid (a proxy server to allow tethering like facility for mobile phones). [This guide](https://code.google.com/p/proxoid/wiki/installationLinux) says that I need to restart the process `udev` similar to (in Ubuntu):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

`lsusb` does list the mobile phone but I do not see a running process or a binary named as `udev`.
There is a process `udevd` on CentOS `/sbin/udevd`. Is it the same as `udev`? I could not find specific information to CentOS as the centos.org site seems to be down for several hours now.

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions aren't very good. Udev automatically detects changes to the rules files in normal circumstances, you don't need to restart it after changing or adding a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. On the other hand, the rules are applied when a device is plugged in: if you change the rules, it doesn't affect devices that are already connected. The instructions are telling you to restart the udev subsystem to apply the new rules.

If you already know the rules you want to add, add them first, then plug your device in. If you do things in that order, you don't need to do anything else.

You may need to first plug in your phone to find its vendor ID, then write a rule accordingly. If so, the easiest way to apply your changes is to unplug your phone and plug it back in after you've added the rule. Alternatively, to reapply the rules for a particular device, run

```
udevadm --trigger --attr-match=idVendor=xxxx
```

where xxxx is your phone's vendor ID.

See also [How to reload udev rules without reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot/39485#39485)

Answer (score 0):

`udev` is very much integrated into modern Linux systems, there should be nothing to install or run.

Comment: It seems to me you did not bother to read the question properly?  It was not asking about how to install udev (which does have installed/uninstallable/reinstallable userland components such as udevd), it was asking about *how to restart the udev service* which is a pretty normal straightforward thing for which there are normal straightforward commands.

Comment: ...to be fair I just noticed the *title* of the question did include the word "Installing".  Still, a quick read might have made this clear (?)

Comment: @goldilocks Udev notices changes to its configuration directories through inotify (I think even CentOS 5 is not so ancient as to predate that). The only time you'd restart udev is when upgrading it.

Comment: @Gilles : Yes -- I addressed that (implicitly) in my answer (see *"However"*).  The issue here is not mine, it's from the google code doc the OP is consulting (might help to actually: *read* the original post, read the link the post refers to, read my answer).  I'm not saying vonbrand is wrong, just that his/her answer is not particularly informative or helpful.

Comment: @goldilocks Your answer is correct but mostly irrelevant. The problem is not to re-read the rules file, that happens automatically. The problem is to apply the new rules. See my answer.

Comment: @Gilles : It's irrelevant to you because you already understand a) the difference between a process and a service b) udev, what it is and how to use it.  The OP obviously does not, so that needs to be sorted out.  I focussed on (a) because (b) is in fact less relevant (as you say, the rules are reloaded automatically, so *anything and everything* is irrelevant.  Strictly, the questioner does not not need to know or do anything...)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to restart the process udev similar to (in ubuntu) sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart

Actually those instructions do not use the term *process* and what you are referring to there a *service*, which is not quite the same thing.  There probably is a `udevd` process running on centOS as part of the udev service, try:

```
ps -A | grep udev
```

In any case, if you want to restart the *service*, you should do it properly.  If your centOS uses systemd:

```
systemctl list-units | grep udev
```

On fedora it's called `systemd-udevd.service`.  You can leave the "service" off:

```
systemctl restart systemd-udevd
```

If it doesn't use systemd, try:

```
service --status-all | grep udev
```

Then if it's called udevd:

```
service udevd restart
```

## However...

I don't think you actually have to do that if you just want to load some rules.  There's a chance you don't have to do anything (test that if you can) or:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Should do it.

Comment: Reloading the rules happens automatically. What you need to do is *apply* the new rules, either by plugging the device out and back in, or running `udevadm trigger`.