# How to bind USB device under a static name?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino which sometimes gets bound to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and other times to `/dev/ttyUSB1`, making my script fail.

I do not want to enumerate all the possibilities of where my device could be, but I'd rather have it be bound somewhere static, e.g. `/dev/arduino`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Just write a simple udev-rule which will assign symlink /dev/arduino to right devise by its VID & PID.

Comment: Check arch-wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Writing_udev_rules

Comment: After you've changed the rules, see [How to reload udev rules without reboot?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/39485#39485)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As suggested, you can add some udev rules. I edited the `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` to contain:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="my_uart"
```

You can check for the variables of your device by running

```
udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)
```

There is a more in depth guide you can read on http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Comment: Worked like a charm. One question: How to exit `udevam`? And it is important to note that `my_uart` creates the symlink under `/dev/my_uart`. I first wrote `/dev/arduino` the first time and it failed whilst `arduino` is sufficient.

Comment: `udevadm` should exit by itself when it's done.

Comment: Then for some unknown reason it froze the terminal session to my Raspberry Pi while generating the report.

Comment: What's the benefit of doing your command vs. just `udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: Nice - now my esp32 and my ft232h for debugging get swapped if I plug them in different orders, but the aliases stay the same :-)

Comment: Weird how my converter has the exact same vendor ID and product ID :/

Comment: Is `ACTION=="add"` required? What does it do? Other examples do not have it; it is also not explained in the link to the guide. Also, what would be the difference between `SYMLINK+="my_uart"` and `NAME="my_uart"`?

Comment: I did the above followed by a `udevadm trigger` but now /dev/oswitch points to /dev/bus/usb/001/002 while /dev/ttyUSB0 points to nothing in particular. I also get some gibberish when I `cat /dev/oswitch` but not when I `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Answer (score 52):

The rule syntax above may work on some distributions, but did not work on mine (Raspbian). Since I never found a single document that explains all the ins and outs, I wrote my own, to be found [here](http://rolfblijleven.blogspot.nl/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html). This is what it boils down to.

1. Find out what's on ttyUSB:

   ```
   dmesg | grep ttyUSB
   ```
2. List all attributes of the device:

   ```
   udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSBx --attribute-walk
   ```

   (with your device number(s) instead of x, of course). Pick out a unique identifier set, eg idVendor +  idProduct. You may also need SerialNumber if you have more than one device with the same idVendor and idProduct. SerialNumbers ought to be unique for each device.
3. Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules` with something like this line in it:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", SYMLINK+="your_device_name"
   ```

   assuming you don't need a serial number there, and of course with the numbers for idVendor and idProduct that you found in step 2.
4. Load the new rule:

   ```
   sudo udevadm trigger
   ```

   **Edit 2021, july 6:** While this worked fine on said distribution at the time (2015), on Archlinux, and perhaps other distributions, you may need to *first* do `sudo udevadm control --reload`, if automatic loading fails.
5. Verify what happened:

   ```
   ls -l /dev/your_device_name
   ```

   will show what ttyUSB number the symlink went to. If it's `/dev/ttyUSB1`, then verify who owns that and to which group it belongs:

   ```
   ls -l /dev/ttyUSB1
   ```
6. Then just for the fun of it:

   ```
   udevadm test -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/your_device_name)
   ```

Comment: So is there any solution if the `idVendor` and `idProduct` are exactly the same? (two sensors attached on identical model USB to UART modules)

Comment: @StevenLu Yes, see step 2, do `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB1 --attribute-walk` for both devices and look for serial numbers, they should be unique for each device. If your sensors have no serial number, can you specify what they are?

Comment: that's awesome, i will report back when i try this out

Comment: My $2 USB to UART dongles have serial number 0001. Can't say I'm surprised. Looks like I have to identify the sensors based on their output protocol.

Comment: @StevenLu Bad luck. FTDI USB-UART converters do have a unique serial number, AFAIK. A few extra bucks, but less time to develop.

Comment: If we could get the physical port # on the USB hub (whether internal or external), then we could name things somewhat better.  I haven't found a way to do this.  The USB device numbers are assigned, and not consistently on each boot.

Comment: @mcr Yup. That's the whole point. That's simply the way USB enumeration works. You may want to read about it [here](http://rolfblijleven.blogspot.nl/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html) (easy version) or [here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4290.pdf)

Comment: For anyone else stumbling along this, I was able to make it work with just `ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058", ATTRS{idProduct}=="259f", SYMLINK+="externalhdd"`. The device then appeared at `/dev/externalhdd` after running `sudo udevadm trigger`. This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @RolfBly Without `# udevadm control --reload` the `# udevadm trigger` doesn't use the new/changed rules on Raspberry-Arch in my case.

Answer (score 14):

## The multiple-identical-USB-device problem

I have a Rasperry Pi with four cameras. I take pix with `fswebcam` which identifies the cameras as `/dev/video0` .. `video3`.  Sometimes the camera  is `video0`, `vide02`, `video4` and `video6` but we can forget about that for now.

I need a persistent ID to identify a camera number so that, e.g. `video0` is always the same camera because I caption the pictures.  Unfortunately this doesn’t happen reliably - on boot, the cameras get enumerated as `video0`..`video3` but not always the same way.

The cameras all have the same ID and serial number.

The solution to this problem involves udev rules, but there's a lot of fishhooks there as well.

If you issue the command

```
udevadm info –attribute-walk –path=/dev/video0
```

you get a screed of output but the salient bits are

```
KERNEL=”video0”, SUBSYSTEM=”video4linux” and KERNELS=”1:1.2.4:1.0”.
```

The KERNELS bit is a USB hub port.  With four cameras there are four of these - they do not change on reboot , but the `video{x}` associated with a port *may* change.

So we need a udev rule to tie a video number to a USB hub port -  something like:

```
KERNEL==”video0”,SUBSYSTEM=”video4linux”,KERNELS==”1:1.2.4:1.0”,SYMLINK+=”camera0”
```

Looks simple – access the camera with

```
fswebcam –d  $realpath /dev/camera0
```

Except it doesn’t work – if you put this in a udev rule and the system has allocated video0 (on boot) to a different port, the udev rule is ignored.  The symlink to `/dev/camera0` basically says `no such device`. Square one.

What we want is to bind a symlink to a USB hub address, not a `video{x}` number. It took a Python program.

First step was to run

```
fswebcam –d /dev/video${x}  tst.jpg
```

for `x` between 1 and 8. The existence of `tst.jpg` after each call identifies whether there is a camera on this video number. From this make a list of active video numbers. My experience has been that it is either `0,1,2,3` or `0,2,4,6` for cameras I have used.

Others may of course build this list using a different process.

Then for each video number in the list run

```
udevadm info –attribute-walk –path=/dev/videox > dd
```

and extract the `KERNELS= line` from `dd`. From this process you end up with a list of the USB port addresses for the cameras.  Sort this list so that at the next step, you always process it in the same order. Call this the "address list".

Run the `udevadm … > dd` thing again and make a list that looks like

```
KERNEL==”video0”, SUBSYSTEM=”video4linux”,KERNELS==”1:1.2.4:1.0 ”,SYMLINK+=”camerax”. Call this the “video list”.
```

Now step through the address list - for each entry find the corresponding entry from the video list. Create a new list that looks like a collection of lines like

```
KERNEL==”video0”, SUBSYSTEM=”video4linux”,KERNELS==”1:1.2.4:1.0 ”,SYMLINK+=”camera2”
```

The x (symlink number) is replaced by the sequence number in the address list.

Now you have a udev rule that works. A symlink that is tied to a USB hub address no matter what video number is allocated to that port at boot.

Write the final list into a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/cam.rules`. Run `udevadm trigger` to activate it and the job is done.  `/dev/camera2` will be the same camera (USB port) regardless of its video number.

Comment: Welcome on unix stackexchange. Please format your answer using markdown. I just did it for you. Also keep in mind that we want answers to be to the point. This reads more like a blog entry (which is not entirely bad) yet it's not that helpful to first read about approaches that didn't work. You may scrap that part.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new here.  I have researched this problem for months. I did find others struggling with the same problem and I did not find an answer that worked for me. Just so I know, where would you advise that I post something like this? I did restrain myself and not include the Python source :-)

Comment: I think this answer is great. :-) It shows an approach to take when the serial number answer is not an option. It outlines the thought process behind the answer and why the first more obvious option doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of good answers here, but they all work for a specific VID:PID. After a lot of fiddling with udev rules for multiple brands of serial adapters, I find this simple udev rule works best for me:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", SYMLINK+="tty.usb-$attr{devpath}"
```

It yields persistent symlinks based on the path to the device on the USB bus, for example:

```bsh
$ lsusb -t # output filtered for tty devices only
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 20, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 20, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=cp210x, 12M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=cp210x, 12M
                |__ Port 5: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
                    |__ Port 5: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=cp210x, 12M
$ ls -alF /dev/tty.usb*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug  2 10:33 /dev/tty.usb-1.2.2.3 -> ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug  2 10:33 /dev/tty.usb-1.2.2.4 -> ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug  2 09:04 /dev/tty.usb-1.2.2.5.5 -> ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug  2 10:40 /dev/tty.usb-1.2.3 -> ttyACM0
```

Comment: On some systems `ll` isn't an alias of `ls -alF` and the path might be different, `ls -alF /dev/ttyUSB*`

Answer (score 3):

I was also able to find a unique device in `/dev/serial/by-id`.  I haven't tried a reboot yet, but the files in that directory were just links to the appropriate device file (`ttyACM[0-9]`).`

I am running arch linux on Raspberry Pi, but I stumbled across them just by doing a `find` for filenames containing "Arduino".  My python programs run fine using those files as devices to read/write data to/from my Arduinos (so far, two on a single Pi).

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

Serial devices are listed deterministically by path in `/dev/serial/by-path` with a verbose naming scheme that represents the physical device connection. This name will always be the same as long as the device is plugged into the same USB port.  These are symlinks to the dynamic naming of devices in /dev/ttyUSB*

As long as you always have your arduino plugged into the same port on your machine or USB hub it will always result in the same path name in the `by-path` directory.  You could then just symlink to the appropriate by-path filename to make sure your script always works and has a memorable name.  This solution works even if you have several arduinos connected to your system.

If I plugged an arduino into the second USB2.0 port (`4.2`) on my system I could always access it at `/dev/arduino` using this symlink definition:

```
ln -s /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.2:1.0-port0 /dev/arduino
```

**Background Info**

The ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1 naming scheme depends on the time order of connecting devices and the next available index. The same device may show up with a new index if the system was unable to free all handles to it from a previous connection of the device or even if an error caused the device to renumerate and the previous file handle was unavailable still. The by-path directory symlinks always point the constant physical port name to the latest ttyUSB# instance of a device connection.

```
$ ls -la /dev/serial/by-path/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 200 Feb  8 21:46 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  80 Feb  7 22:17 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB4            
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0          
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.1:1.1-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1          
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.1:1.2-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2          
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.1:1.3-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB3          
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.2:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB6          
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.3.3.1.2.4:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB7  
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  13 Feb  8 21:46 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.3.3.3:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB8
```

In this example I have five USB-serial devices connected as well as several hubs. The "`pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-`" prefix is always the same because all of my USB chips are on the same PCI bus. If you had a thunderbolt connected USB hub this number would probably change. The subsequent numbering scheme represents the path to the device on a specific USB port. For the symlink beginning `0:1` I'm not sure what the 0 is, 1 is the address of the USB3 chip on my motherboard, `4.1`, `4.2`, `4.3` are the three builtin USB2 ports on my system. The device connected to port `4.1` is a USB-serial adapter with four serial ports on a single device, therefore it has final values of  `1.0`, `1.1`, `1.2`, and `1.3` to signify all of the ttys on the single device.

`ttyUSB7` is a USB-Serial adapter plugged into a long string of USB hubs. `ttyUSB8` is plugged into the same string of hubs but only part way along the string. The ttyUSB* naming shows you what order I plugged the devices in. You can see that /dev/ttyUSB5 is missing.  That is because I unplugged a device that regularly fails to get all of its file handles released so when I plugged it in again that number wasn't reused. Despite that I can still reach the device under it's new filename because I have the by-path symlink.

**Alternative Naming Scheme**

On my CentOS system these `by-path` symlinks are being created with UDEV rules from the default system ruleset in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules`.

Since my system doesn't have the ability to extend the PCI bus the `pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-` prefix never changes and is just more typing to point to a specific port. For the sake of convenience in having a shorter naming scheme, the UDEV rule below uses a variation of the `60-serial.rules` to create a symlink in `/dev/` which strips `pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-` off the beginning of the link name and `-port0` off the end.

My new rule relies on the `ID_PATH` environment variable having been defined (ID_PATH contains the long version device path - `"pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.3.3.1.2.4:1.0-port0"`). You don't have to care about how `ID_PATH` gets created, you just need to run your rule after it exists in order to use/manipulate it. UDEV rules are executed in numerical naming order so I just named my rule with a 90 prefix, `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-usbtty.rules`, rather than trying to find out when `ID_PATH` got defined and then it was available to modify.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo USB_PATH=$( echo ${ID_PATH} | cut --delimiter=- -f 4 )'", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB.$env{USB_PATH}"
```

This rule creates shorter names and puts them in the `/dev/` directory for my convenience.

```
$ ls -ld /dev/ttyUSB.*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:1:1.0 -> ttyUSB4                           
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.1:1.0 -> ttyUSB0                         
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.1:1.1 -> ttyUSB1                         
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.1:1.2 -> ttyUSB2                         
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.1:1.3 -> ttyUSB3                         
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.2:1.0 -> ttyUSB6                         
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.3.3.1.2.4:1.0 -> ttyUSB7                 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Feb  8 21:46 /dev/ttyUSB.0:4.3.3.3:1.0 -> ttyUSB8
```

**More Involved Naming Code**

It is nice to have a one-liner UDEV rule,  but if it were any more complex  (and arguably now) it would need a separate script file to be intelligible and functional. If you did want to create such a script the example below could be a starting point. You can substitute `/bin/sh` for any other executable file.

UDEV environment variables are available in the called program
and standard output (e.g. echo/print statements)
of the form `ENV_VAR='VALUE'`
cause new environment variables to become available.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", IMPORT{program}="/path/to/script", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB.$env{USB_PATH}"
```

```
#!/bin/sh

p=$(echo "${ID_PATH}" | cut -d '-' -f 4)
echo "USB_PATH='$p'"
```

One last gotcha I ran into that might force a separte script rather than the one-liner is quote escaping. You can see in the script version of the rule that the more standard `-d '-'` is passed to `cut`, whereas in the oneliner `--delimiter=-` was required.  As far as I can tell UDEV doesn't allow quote escaping, so specifying the delimiter without a quote is necessary. If you try `-d -` then the dash is interpreted as a flag to `cut` rather than a delimeter character.

Comment: (1) You obviously put a lot of work into this. But, maybe I’m missing something — I don’t see how it answers the question. The OP wants to write a script that access his device without needing to determine its dynamic name. How can he do that? (2) What is the `ID_PATH` variable? (3) It’s difficult (if not impossible) to use quotes in a `{program}="/bin/sh -c '…'"` command because it’s already quoted twice. But what does that have to do with anything? You can say `-d-` or `-d -` without using quotes. … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Great thoughts.  I've tried to clarify a few points and address each of the issues you listed. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to say that the above worked for me and also automounted the device for me after I had placed an entry in /etc/fstab (and it also calls umount after removal of the stick)

i.e.

/etc/fstab

```
# See /etc/udev/rules.d/5-usb-disk.rules
/dev/backup     /vol/backup     ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/5-usb-stick.rules

```
#
# the next line creates a symlink to this disk drive called /dev/backup 
# i.e.
#   root:# ls -la /dev/backup 
#   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jul 22 19:33 /dev/backup -> sg0

# Backup usb stick - create /dev/backup
# ATTRS{model}=="Cruzer Blade    "
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{model}=="Cruzer Blade    ", SYMLINK+="backup"

# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{model}=="Cruzer Blade    ", RUN+="/bin/umount /vol/backup"
```

So after inserting my usb stick I get:

```
root:# mount | grep sd
/dev/sda1 on /vol/backup type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules
```

Enter the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A1111111", SYMLINK+="ttyMyUSB"
```

## To get the required information

### Vendor/product ID

```
$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0403: 6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
[...]
```

### ATTRS{serial}

```
$ udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep {serial} | head -n1
ATTRS{serial}=="A1111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set a permanent name for a specific port, and not for a specific device connected to the computer, so I tied to KERNELS

```
sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb1-3.rules
KERNELS=="1-3:1.0", SYMLINK+="usb_3"
```

(yes, after disconnecting the usb, the link is also deleted, otherwise I had doubts)

Even before I made the rule above, I couldn't figure out for a long time why my udev rule didn't work, the reason was that I was setting ATTRS from different "sections" in the output of `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB1 --attribute-walk`.

After I fixed it, everything started working fine

To reset the rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```