# How to bind arduino as a fix block-device --- /dev/ttyACM0?

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, arduino, bind-mount

I want to bind my Arduino Mega as /dev/ttyACM0. Sometimes, it turns out to be /dev/ttyACM0 and sometimes as /dev/ttyACM1.

I have taken help from this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name) and this [tutorial](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

Someone please help me to achieve that as there are only 2 entries in /etc/udev/rules.d :-

1. 20-crystalhd.rules
2. 98-kexec.rules

The output of `udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyACM0)` :-

> Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
>   walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
>   found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format. A rule to
>   match, can be composed by the attributes of the device and the
>   attributes from one single parent device.

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/tty/ttyACM0':
KERNEL=="ttyACM0"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
DRIVER==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0':
KERNELS=="2-1.5:1.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="02"
ATTRS{bmCapabilities}=="6"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="02"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5':
KERNELS=="2-1.5"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{devpath}=="1.5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341"
ATTRS{speed}=="12"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="c0"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0001"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{serial}=="55431313937351C05151"
ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="17"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Arduino (www.arduino.cc)"
ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0042"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="02"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1':
KERNELS=="2-1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="70"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2':
KERNELS=="usb2"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0310"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="42"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64 ehci_hcd"
ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0':
KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
ATTRS{irq}=="23"
ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x104d"
ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
ATTRS{companion}==""
ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTRS{local_cpus}=="000f"
ATTRS{device}=="0x1c26"
ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x9081"
ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
SUBSYSTEMS==""
DRIVERS==""
```

***Where should I edit my entries in which files and how. Please explain in somewhat depth as I am much naive!!***
Please help me establish this. It's already taking my mind and  mood off.

Comment: Note that on modern versions of `udev`, the `/etc/udev/rules.d` is only for rules customized for that specific system (either by sysadmin or by other rules or some other automation). The majority of udev rules can be found at `[/usr]/lib/udev/rules.d` instead (whether or not there is `/usr` at the beginning of the path depends on distribution).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of a linux system right now, but I would start by tracking down what writes `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and use that as a template.

Specifically, every time a wifi device is plugged in, the interface name, such as `wlan0`, `wlan1`, etc. becomes fixed based on some device attribute (I presume MAC address).

You can follow the same convention to create your own udev rules for the Arduino device.