# Create friendly-named "device-partition" devices - /dev/mapper?

Tags: udev, devices, device-mapper

I have a few USB disks and partitions which I would like to refer to in an intuitive way.

I know it is possible to [use `udev` to create a persistent named device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name) eg   `/dev/seagate2tb`.

Is it possible to have a disk named `/dev/seagate2tb` with partitions labelled `movies` and `fat32` and automatically have device names created along the lines of:

- `/dev/mapper/seagate2tb-movies`
- `/dev/mapper/seagate2tb-fat32`

or

- `/dev/seagate2tb/movies`
- `/dev/seagate2tb/fat32`

Comment: Would using LVM an option ?

Comment: I'm after a solution which would work with partitions that Windows can also read.

Comment: Is `/dev/disk/by-label` or `/dev/disk/by-partlabel` good enough?

Comment: `by-label` doesn't give me anything about partitions. I guess I could include disk info in the partition name and then use `by-partlabel`.