# Binding arduino to static port name

Tags: udev, hardware, serial-port, ide, arduino

My question is an extension to the one asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name).

The Udev rule seem to be applied properly and i can now distingush my arduinos uniquely from an external script by referring to links files created as `/dev/arduino` and `/dev/arduino2`.

The rules in the /etc/udev/rules.d is

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", ATTRS{serial}=="OMITTED1",  SYMLINK+="arduino1"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", ATTRS{serial}=="OMITTED2",  SYMLINK+="arduino2"
```

The issue now is, how can i have those link names display in the arduino IDE.
The Arduino IDE still recognises them as `/dev/ttyACMx`. Assigning random ACMx numbers on each assignment.

I would like the arduino IDE show the devices as `/dev/arduino1` etc rather than `/dev/ttyACMx`. Can this also be handled through a udev file or a unix hack.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, if that matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Not even one? :-/ . Could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Here how it works with Arduino IDE 1.0.x:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=/dev/your_port_names_here:/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Also, you can add this to your ~/.profile for global use.

**Port scanning by IDE will be limited to listed ports only, so don't bother to add all your /dev/tty* stuff here!**