# How to reserve a drive letter/name for a specific type of hardware

Tags: mount, udev

I am a bit struggling with this topic.

I have a server box with one ssd drive. **/dev/sda**

Further does it have a CFast slot which occasionally is occupied by a card.
The card is recognized as hard drive and will by default have **/dev/sdb** assigned as drive letter.

To finalize the setup comes a USB stick into play.
Depending on the presence of a presence of a CFast card is the stick assigned to **/dev/sdb or /dev/sdc**

It must have /dev/sdc in order to have some properly working scripts.
The USB stick may vary.

**So how do I either reserve sdb for hard disks (CFast) or assign USB sticks to /dev/sdc and upwards?**

I do believe UUID in fstab wont work as the stick may change from time to time.
Something scripted with udev?

Cheers
Jan

Comment: Do the solutions described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name help you?

Comment: Do not use `/dev/sdx` in scripts. Use the UUID --> `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`. As long as the drive is not formatted, the UUID will not change.

Comment: The use of UUIDs is not feasible. Too much dynamics here. CFast and USB stick may vary and thus the UUIDs too

Comment: @markgraf. I have stumbled over that thread to. Not sure yet if it works but that was my intuitive first shot as I got this topic on my desk

Comment: Similar to `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, there's also `/dev/disk/by-path`, which uses the PCI paths to identify disks, The CFast slot and the USB ports should show up differently there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  figured it out up to a certain degree.

The solution is udev.
You can call with

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/sdb1 --attribute-walk
```

a list of all attributes used by category from the end point to the root.

I then created a local rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules

That rule contains

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/usb_load.sh"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/usb_unload.sh"
```

It compares events and if SUBSYSTEMS, ACTION and ENV{DEVTYPE} matches the RUN+= executes 2 shell scripts I have placed in bin.
It is run as root so no permission issue ahead.

don't forget

```
udevadm control --reload
```

In order to reread the rules

The solution can for sure be improved as the rules are capable of more but for now it is a good solution for me. I will tweak it on time.