# How to bind HIDRAW device under a static name?

Tags: udev

this question was asked [several times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name) with regards to generic USB devices. However, udev approach doesn't seem to work with HIDRAW devices.

I've tried to write something like the following to `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`:

```
 ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16d6", ATTRS{product}=="JA-100 Flexi", SYMLINK+="my_device"
```

But this maps parent USB device, not the HIDRAW one. So, how can I persist the name for hidraw in case it changes after reconnect from, say, hidraw0 to hidraw1?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the hidraw device

```
dmesg | grep "hidraw"
```

Then you need to get its attributes

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/hidraw* --attribute-walk
```

where * is the number of the device (e.g. hidraw5). From this you'll need to find the `ATTRS{id}`.

Then create a *rules* file on RPi with the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb-serial.rules
```

modify the file with the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{id}=="00241011", SYMLINK+="hidraw_static"
```

where `ATTRS{id}` is the device's id from earlier and `SYMLINK` is the name you choose.

Run the following commands after saving this file

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
sudo udevadm trigger
```

Check that the new name *points* to the correct hidraw*

```
ls -l /dev/hidraw_static
```

should look something like this

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 14 10:41 /dev/hidraw_static -> hidraw6
```

This worked for a Bluetooth-connected barcode scanner connected to a RPi 3b+.