# Mapping USB device to fixed bus/device #

Tags: usb, usb-device, lsusb

Whenever I reconnect my USB device (a OnePlus 10T smartphone) to a CentOS 7 server or reboot it its device # on the bus changes as can be seen here:

```
Before: Bus 002 Device 052: ID 22d9:2765 OPPO Electronics Corp. Oppo N1
After:  Bus 002 Device 055: ID 22d9:2765 OPPO Electronics Corp. Oppo N1
```

Is there a way to lock those bus and device # to any fixed values and map them to device vendor:product IDs 22d9:2765 somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind USB device under a static name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name)

Comment: @Peregrino69: Thanks so much - I'll need to experiment with that udev method now.

Comment: @Peregrino69: Seems like (unless I'm misinterpreting it) it's about giving the device a permanent *name* though (somewhere under /dev). My challenge is somewhat different then - to keep it on the same USB bus/device # assuming it's possible at all.

Comment: Why exactly do you think you need to do this? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: to only have to map my USB device to a VM running on that server *once*.

Comment: Sorry, I did slightly misunderstand. I did some testing, and the same way every time I connect my phone, `lsusb` shows it on the same Bus but as different Device. I found the device info first under `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/`; every reconnection increased `devnum`  after a reboot under `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1`

Comment: @Peregrino69: Same here, in fact I noticed that whenever I reconnect or reboot mine its devnum goes up by 3 (always on the same bus) while whenever I map it to a VM running on the server it goes up by 1. I'll be fine with it changing though if the method someone suggested in my parallel thread works: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734831/issues-mapping-usb-device-to-vm .

Comment: Let's hope you get there. At least I've learned again something new :-)