# udev: use usb programmer without needing sudo

Tags: udev

I'm using the `mspdebug` programmer to connect to a device.

`mspdebug` will only connect to the device when I use `sudo mspdebug`. If I don't use `sudo`, `mspdebug` can't find the device.

How can I connect to the device without needing `sudo`?

The device in particular I want to connect to is listed here:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2047:0013 Texas Instruments MSP Tools Driver
```

I have these `udev` rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/46-TI_launchpad.rules`:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0451", ATTR{idProduct}=="f432", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
ATTR{idVendor}=="2047", ATTR{idProduct}=="0013", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

I am in the `plugdev` group:

```
$ id $USER
uid=1000(earthishome) gid=1000(earthishome) groups=1000(earthishome),10(wheel),977(pkg-build),1001(plugdev),974(vboxusers),1003(docker)
```

### Edit 1

#### Tracking down the device

When plugging in the device, two ttys are created: `ttyACM0` and `ttyACM1`:

```
$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[21580.524390] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.527712] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.528138] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
KERNEL[21580.528301] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.528453] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.528623] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.528892] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.529451] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/tty/ttyACM1 (tty)
KERNEL[21580.529600] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.529746] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.529892] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3 (usb)
KERNEL[21580.530075] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.563378] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.570495] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.572104] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.573582] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.573663] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.577042] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.578987] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.579357] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
UDEV  [21580.580712] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/tty/ttyACM1 (tty)
UDEV  [21580.585516] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.585592] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [21580.596329] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 (usb)
```

#### Using strace

There is a "permission denied" error when trying to open `/dev/ttyACM0` that doesn't happen when I run `strace sudo mspdebug tilib`.

```
$ strace mspdebug tilib
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=5000000}, NULL) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=5000000}, NULL) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=5000000}, NULL) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=5000000}, NULL) = 0
```

#### Using udevadm to find the device and its parents

```
$ udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/ttyACM0

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0':
    KERNEL=="ttyACM0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bmCapabilities}=="2"
    ATTRS{interface}=="MSP Debug Interface"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="14"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="B1443A5106001800"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{product}=="MSP Tools Driver"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="2047"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="140"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0013"
    ATTRS{configuration}=="MSP430 USB"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Texas Instruments"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="268"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0506"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 5.6.19-300.fc32.x86_64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="12"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x9d2f"
    ATTRS{dbc}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{irq}=="126"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x082a"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x21"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

### Edit 2

I was able to solve this thanks to the troubleshooting tips in the comments.

#### TLDR

There were two things that needed to change:

1. Move the file from `46-TI_launchpad.rules` to `94-TI_launchpad.rules`
2. Change `ATTR` to `ATTRS` in the rule as shown:

   ATTRS{idVendor}=="2047", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0013", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"

#### Details

As both Artem S. Tashkinov and meuh pointed out, the rule was being overwritten by later rules. Renaming the file in the 90s ensures it'll run towards the end and not be overwritten by earlier rules.

Using `udevadm info -a`, as dirkt suggested, prints the whole device chain.
Looking at the device chain, the actual device itself doesn't have the attributes `idVendor` and `idProduct` defined; these attributes are defined in the parent device.
In order to match those attributes, `ATTR` must be changed to `ATTRS` to match attributes in parent devices.

Comment: Please check this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200194/how-to-debug-an-udev-rule-in-etc-udev-rules-d

Comment: Debugging udev-rules is a bit of a PITA. First check *which* device file is created with group `plugdev` if you plug it in. The most likely error is that this is not the device file that's actually needed by `mspdebug`, but you need a different device atop that one. But that's impossible to say without seeing all important udev-rules, and running `mspdebug`. Use `udevadm` to get an idea of the device chain, and `strace` to see which file `mspdebug` actually wants to open before it errors out.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyACM1`?

Comment: Start with `ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="tty",` and change `ATTR` to `ATTRS` to check the parents. See [writing_udev_rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html). Also consider renumbering your file higher, as later `GROUP=` settings may override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this thanks to the troubleshooting tips in the comments of the question.

### TLDR

There were two things that needed to change:

1. Move the file from `46-TI_launchpad.rules` to `94-TI_launchpad.rules`
2. Change `ATTR` to `ATTRS` in the rule as shown:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2047", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0013", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

### Details

As both Artem S. Tashkinov and meuh pointed out, the 46 rule was being overwritten by later rules. Renaming the file in the 90s ensures it'll run towards the end and not be overwritten by earlier rules.

Using `udevadm info -a`, as dirkt suggested, prints the whole device chain. Looking at the device chain, the actual device itself doesn't have the attributes `idVendor` and `idProduct` defined; these attributes are defined in the parent device. In order to match attributes in parent devices, `ATTR` must be changed to `ATTRS`.