# Systemd exec works only once after daemon-reload

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that starts from a udev rule:

```
[Unit]
Description=Open DSLR camera device

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/tmp/test.sh"
```

`/tmp/test.sh` doesn't do much yet:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "qwer" >> /tmp/dslr-udev-test.txt
```

I don't think the udev rule is relevant (it triggers on connecting my DSLR camera on usb). Here it is anyway:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{product}=="Canon Digital Camera", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="dslr-device.service"
```

After running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and turning the camera on, the file `/tmp/dslr-udev-test.txt` shows new content. But only once! Turning the camera off and on again shows no new content.

After running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` again, the file shows new content once upon turning on the camera, then no more upon further camera restarts.

What is preventing the service's `ExecStart` from running more than once after daemon-reload?

Comment: Have you tried [troubleshooting the udev part](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200194/how-to-debug-an-udev-rule-in-etc-udev-rules-d) using `udevadm monitor`?

Comment: Does `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl start dslr.service` add a line to your file?

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status dslr-device.service` after the first execution?