# Using USB to Ethernet adapter (ASIX AX88179 driver) on Linux Mint 20.2

Tags: networking, linux-mint, drivers, ethernet

I am relatively new to Linux, and I am using Mint 20.2, on an HP Elitebook 840 G7.

I have bought a TP-Link USB-to-Ethernet adapter, based on the ASIX AX88179 chipset:

[USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Network Adapter](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-converter/ue305/)

I have been able to (compile and) install the driver, and the device is correctly listed in the system report.

However, the adapter does not work.

I am aware that I need to create a new Network Interface for the device, but I don't know how.
Among other things, I don't know how to read the MAC address of the device, to follow the instructions of this post:

[How to set up an usb/ethernet interface in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386162/how-to-set-up-an-usb-ethernet-interface-in-linux)

This page seems also useful, but it is too much for me:

[Adding new, undocumented features into a kernel driver](https://jg.sn.sg/ax88179/)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by updating the system to Linux Mint 20.3!