# How to add a block device to the udev database?

Tags: lvm, udev

I get this for my all LVM commands:

```
WARNING: Device /dev/dm-6 not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds.
```

After that, it works, but all of them require about a half minute waiting.

`udevadm info /dev/dm-5` (another volume) shows a pretty okay device. Comparing this to an `udevadm info /dev/dm-6`, I get a surprisingly short list:

> ```
> P: /devices/virtual/block/dm-6
> N: dm-6
> L: 0
> E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/dm-6
> E: DEVNAME=/dev/dm-6
> E: DEVTYPE=disk
> E: MAJOR=253
> E: MINOR=6
> E: SUBSYSTEM=block
> ```

I think, `/dev/dm-6` was somehow forgotten by the udev. I think I could easily fix it by simply asking udev to re-load this device. How can I do that?

[Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242689) I've read, turning off udev_sync and udev_rules in lvm.conf might work, but I would prefer a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks, my problem is solved by [reloading the udev rules without reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot). An

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

did what I wanted.