# USB hard drive not recognized

Tags: mount, usb-drive

My computer runs Cruncbang Linux (debian based). When I try to connect my friends external USB hard drive, it's not recognized. `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't show any new devices when I plug the USB drive in. `lsusb` does show the device. If I save the output of `ls -la /dev` to a file before and after plugging the device in. Then diff I get this `sg3`. This is the file:

`crw-------   1 root root       21,   3 Sep 23 20:39 sg3`

The first letter in the line is `c` which means character special file.

When I tail `/var/log/syslog` and plug the USB drive in I get this output:

```
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.116178] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.250196] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0740
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.250206] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.250213] usb 2-4: Product: My Passport 0740
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.250219] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.250225] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 575834314136314838333937
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang kernel: [  642.251082] scsi4 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.1/usb2/2-4"
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang dbus[2208]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks' (using servicehelper)
Sep 23 20:20:54 crunchbang dbus[2208]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks'
Sep 23 20:20:55 crunchbang kernel: [  643.250209] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0740 1003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Sep 23 20:20:55 crunchbang kernel: [  643.250691] scsi 4:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Sep 23 20:20:55 crunchbang kernel: [  643.255046] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Sep 23 20:20:55 crunchbang kernel: [  643.256741] scsi 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
Sep 23 20:21:56 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
Sep 23 20:21:57 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
Sep 23 20:21:58 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
Sep 23 20:21:59 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
Sep 23 20:22:00 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
Sep 23 20:22:01 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
Sep 23 20:22:01 crunchbang kernel: [  643.263011] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk.............................................................not responding...
Sep 23 20:22:02 crunchbang udevd[2788]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -b scsi:t-0x0d' [3945]
```

A [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/mounting-usb-drive-that-is-not-recognized) suggests to comment out MTP catch all rules. I don't know much about MTP but the link that that question points to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119676 suggests it has something to do with `/etc/udev/rules.d/libmtp.rules`. I don't have this file on my computer. But I do have these three:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/10-vboxdrv.rules
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here and how I might go about mounting this drive.

Comment: [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2136506.html) suggests that this may be a hardware issue, caused by the USB controller on your mainboard.

Comment: I agree with @MartinvonWittich these sort of errors almost always mean bad controller or disk.

Comment: The thread specifically points to the USB controller of the mainboard though, not the hard disk controller :) Sounds like some kind of incompatibility between the USB host and the USB interface of that disk.

Comment: I should mention that other external hard drives work fine with my computer. Just this one doesn't. It is my friends. I'm having a look as it doesn't work on his computer.