# USB Stick recognized but not mountable

Tags: arch-linux, mount, usb-drive, dd

I have a USB Stick which is recognized by my laptop but there is no partition to mount. The device is listed in `/dev/` as `sdb` but no partition `/dev/sdb1`. `fdisk -l` also displays nothing about `/dev/sdb`. I also tried to reread the partition table with `partprobe` which had no effect. I did not update my kernel, rebooted none the less, still same result.

I also found this question: [Mounting USB Drive that is Not Recognized](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/mounting-usb-drive-that-is-not-recognized) which was solved by the answers here [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119676), but those didn't help me since my `/etc/udev/rules.d/` is empty.

`dmesg` outputs the following when I plug in the stick:

```
usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access 2238 PRAM 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`lsusb` displays my stick:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13fe:3100 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 2/4 GB stick
```

The output of `udevadm monitor` is:

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[475.967958] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2 (usb)
KERNEL[475.968047] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[475.968467] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7 (scsi)
KERNEL[475.968757] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/scsi_host/host7 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [476.071403] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2 (usb)
UDEV  [476.136149] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [476.136834] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7 (scsi)
UDEV  [476.138221] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/scsi_host/host7 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[476.971068] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[476.971147] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[476.971196] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_disk/7:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[476.971334] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_device/7:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[476.971780] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/bsg/7:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[476.971813] add /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[476.971898] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [476.972288] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[476.972597] change /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [476.973246] add /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [476.973710] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [476.974907] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_disk/7:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [476.974949] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_device/7:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [476.975955] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/bsg/7:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [476.986215] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [477.000467] change /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
```

Since it seems that the stick is nearly dead I wanted to make a backup of the data so that I could restore it later. I found this [How Do I Create a Bit-Identical Image of a USB Stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318893/how-do-i-create-a-bit-identical-image-of-a-usb-stick?newreg=85db301534964a7f996de93ad8bcea4b)

So I ran:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/usb.img bs=4M
```

Which resulted in:

```
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: No medium found
```

I also tried the same with `ddrescue` with the same result:

```
ddrescue: Can't open input file: No medium found
```

So do you know if there is any way to access or at least save the data on my stick? Thanks for the help!

**EDIT1**

Today I wanted to post the output of `lsblk` requested in the comments and my stick showed a different behaviour than when I originally asked this question.

`dmesg` displayed the following:

```
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host7: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DT R500          PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 31227904 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdb: sdb1
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] UNKNOWN Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 01 dc 7f 80 00 00 08 00
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 31227776
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880213bcf240
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880213bcf288
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I also connected the stick to my Windows Computer. It could access the stick but there were no files showing.

Comment: What output do you see you run `lsblk`?